# Does promise connection of mysql2 require release?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

This link(https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) has an example to get promise connection from a pool.

```
  // get the client
  const mysql = require('mysql2');
  // create the pool
  const pool = mysql.createPool({host:'localhost', user: 'root', database: 'test'});
  // now get a Promise wrapped instance of that pool
  const promisePool = pool.promise();
  // query database using promises
  const [rows,fields] = await promisePool.query("SELECT 1");
```

Does it require to release the connection after the query?

pool.releaseConnection(promisePool)?

Comment: No. Connection is automatically released when query resolves.

Comment: Thanks. BTW, is it possible to close this quesestion?